# Bootstrap Modal is behind the dark background when NuGet bootstrap css is used

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I can't over my head the modal i have made. It looks like this:
[image]

And I finally realized that the problem was the bootstrap css link from the file I got from Nuget. I haven't changed anything to the bootstrap file I got from NuGet.

But when I use this bs css link
`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css`. It works just fine. >:|

Comment: What's the `Nuget version` of `bootstrap`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it was initially 3.3.7. I tried to downgrade from 3.3.2 but the result is the same.

Comment: Can you replicate the same through `fiddle` or `snippet`?

Comment: but my css file is stored locally. but anyway I used that online bootstrap instead.

Comment: It happened to me when my modal wasn't called properly.

Comment: my modal waas fine. im 100% sure the problem is in the bootstrap's css